# Highlight Parent Menu when on child page also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a simple multilevel menu and a script which works to highlight the menu item irrespective of being parent menu or child menu.

In below example when I am on child page then it will only change the colour of child page, while I also want to change the colour or it parent item.

I tried few thing but it is not working as intended.

[Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpLOm) of what I have so far.
In case that doesn't work, here's a code snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  $('#cssmenu a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active-menu');

  // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
  $('#cssmenu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
    $(this).parents("li a").addClass('active-menu');
  }).addClass('active-menu');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <div id="menu-button"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/en/about-us/">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="#">Gallery </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/photo-gallery/" class="active-menu">Photo Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/video-gallery">Video Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/instagram-gallery">Instagram Gallery</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/en/news/">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/en/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's my new code, but this works but keeps keeps other links highlighted as well:

```js
$('#cssmenu a').filter(function() {
  $(this).parents("li.has-sub").find('a:first').addClass('active-menu');
  return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active-menu');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <div id="menu-button"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/en/about-us/">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
      <span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="#">Gallery </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/photo-gallery/" class="active-menu">Photo Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/video-gallery">Video Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/instagram-gallery">Instagram Gallery</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/en/news/">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/en/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your pen isn't working since no `jquery` has been added there.. Here is the updated **[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpLOm)** and also in this `filter`  `$('#cssmenu a').filter(function () {` in the very first line you have `return` statement.. So whatever below that will not work... I have changed same thing in the Pen given above..

Comment: Your script  breaks doesnt do anything

Comment: It was as it is when you provided a link to your pen bro.. I just added `jquery` and moved `return statement`..

Comment: I am not sure what is with CodePEn, Script which i provided works but doesn't change class for parent menu in-case child page is seleted

Comment: See it doesn't `addClass` because you have `return statement` inside `filter` which will just return the execution back and will not execute anything else attached to it.. So `addClass` to `#cssmenu a` will not work..

Comment: In this case, you want to turn 'Gallery' to red, too? Notice - it is inside span element! Also, you should target .active-class (and find parent, if any) not complete menu....

Comment: Do you want this behavior? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQpgPq

Comment: @nevermind, Yes but in this case when i remove the 'active-menu' class from child then it breaks. Actualy it should add `active-menu` class to child menu and then parent menu also. In my example class is static so your example works other wise it breaks

Comment: Ok... can't test in codepen, give me few minutes...

Comment: I made it work with small change to your code ` $('#cssmenu a').filter(function () {
            $(this).parents("li.has-sub").find('a:first').addClass('active-menu');
            return this.href == url;  
        }).addClass('active-menu');`

Comment: @nevermind, Plz ignore my last comment as it is buggy and keeps all parent classed selected

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is what you were after.

```
var $menu = $("#cssmenu");
//Get the anchor based on the page URL
var $current = $menu.find('a').filter(function() {
    return location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1;
    //Or (whatever works)
    //return location.href === this.href;
});
//Add it's parent's anchor
$current = $current.add($current.closest("li.has-sub").find(' > a'));
//Set the desired class
$current.addClass('active-menu');
```

Here is [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8aqzqx7/) along the same lines.